# ChatterFeed on Vf page as a Popup Window doesnt work as expected

Tags: visualforce, chatter, css

[image]I have a requirement where clicking on a an icon brings up a popup with chatter feed for a particular Entity Id like the image below. I was able to do this but clicking on like or Post or Files doesn`t work

```
<chatter:feed showPublisher="true" entityId="{!taskId}"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.custPopup {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 9999;
    left: 45%;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 650px;
    margin-left: -250px;
    top: 50px;
}
.popupBackground {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.20;
    filter: alpha(opacity 20);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[image: My Vf Page]

i will post the code if required

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? What's the behavior?

Comment: clicking on the post or file does nothing...! like wen u click on Post u get a small dropdown to enter a text and click on post...that doesnt come up.! Not only for Post  ...any icon on this popup acts like a static image..!

Comment: Just to add...... this chatter component works normally  wen i tried to display on parent window

Comment: What are you using to display this popup?

Comment: Just a css styling                                                                                  .custPopup {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 border-width: 2px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 z-index: 9999;
 left: 45%;
 padding: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 
 width: 650px;
 margin-left: -250px;
 top: 50px;
}

.popupBackground {
 background-color: black;
 opacity: 0.20;
 filter: alpha(opacity = 20);
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1;
}

Comment: and in that div tag <chatter:feed showPublisher="true" entityId="{!taskId}"/>

Comment: Please add you vf page code and check if you are getting any error in your browser console.

Comment: ur right...havent seen this.....there are js errors in browser console.. any idea how to fix that? il upload the pic in my question...pls chk it..!

Answer (score 1):

hey guys got it to be working using that chatter component in different page and embedding in an iframe

```
    <apex:outputPanel title="Chatter" layout="block" rendered="{!showWhat=='showChatter'}" style="z-index:4">
       <script src="https://ap2.salesforce.com/jslibrary/1481555358000/sfdc/Chatter.js"/>
        <apex:iframe id="chatter-iframe" src="/apex/ChatterPage?chatterTaskId={!taskId}" width="100%" height="400px" scrolling="true" />

       <apex:form >
           <center><apex:commandButton action="{!closePopup}" status="actStatus" reRender="tstpopup" value="close"/></center>
       </apex:form>
    </apex:outputPanel>
```

Chatter Page:

```
<apex:page Controller="ProjectHomePageController" showHeader="false">


    <chatter:feedWithFollowers showHeader="true" entityId="{!chatterTaskId}"/>


</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public ProjectHomePageController() {
        chatterTaskId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('chatterTaskId');
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. But I'm glad you managed to do it !

Comment: no problem @Martin. Im thankful to u fr spending time on my questionss. Im sure ul help many others like me when they have this requirement:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here must be coming from the `z-index` value of your popup set to `9999`.

All the elements inside your container probably have a z-index inferior to 9999.

Just try to set the `z-index` to your popup to `1`.

Comment: I tried that too ....No Luck....! :(

Comment: Did you try to add `z-index: 2;` to the children inside the popup?

Comment: Yup .....after that ....on hover on like n comment showed me their titles  it means css works bt js for chatter doesnt seem to work...!